# I am trying to convert these 2 lines of Matlab code into python. first line is fine but how could I change the 2nd line?

Tags: python, matlab

This is my MATLAB code. Note that `T_cqi=28`

```
gamma_real=reshape(gamma_dB(:,(length(CQI_init)+1):end),[1,length(CQI_test)*T_cqi]); 
gamma_real=gamma_real(1:(end-(T_cqi-1)));
```

This part in matlab is `(length(CQI_init)+1=180` in python it works with 179

I convert it like this:

```
gamma_real=np.reshape(gamma_dB[:,179:],[1,(CQI_test.size)*T_cqi])
```

which is fine but I am not able to do the second line? how could i do this? what should I write for `end` key word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python, no index for the second indexer automatically refers to the end of the array, so try:

```
gamma_real=gamma_real[: -T_cqi]
```

(No index for the first index refers to the first index which is 0 in Python)

Comment: I think it is not working. with this I am getting this shape (0, 4984) but my shape should be something like this (1,4930) which is in matlab.

Comment: What is the shape before the second line in Python ?

Comment: it is (1,4984) ( the shape of gamma_real)

Comment: Oh ok so if you work with a (1, ...) array, do `gamma_real=gamma_real[:, : -T_cqi]`

Comment: yeah now it is somehow better I got (1, 4956) this shape need 1 more -T_cqi or just -26. I need this shape (1,4930) .. how could I get this?

Comment: gamma_real=gamma_real[:, : -2*T_cqi+2] with this I am getting this shape. but I am not sure it will be fine or not?

Comment: What do you mean, "it will be fine or not" ? This will simply remove (2*T_cqi-2) elements from the end of the array. Is that waht you want ?

Comment: Yeah I guess it will be fine. I changed this shape (1, 4956) to (1,4930) just removed the remaining 26 elements from this array

Comment: Ok glad it worked ! Can you mark the topic as solved if everything is ok ?